# Bootstrap :active li Opera bug

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working with Bootstrap for the past few days and seem to have encountered a bug when using Opera. Upon the page loading the navbar should have a list that reads like so:

```
<li class="hidden active">
<li class="page-scroll">
<li class="page-scroll">
<li class="page-scroll">
<li class="page-scroll">
```

When the user scrolls to a new page (or clicks a `li`) then the corresponding `li` becomes `:active` and it changes color appropriately etc.
This works perfectly fine on all browsers I've used (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Android Chrome and Safari.)
However, sadly on Opera  the list renders like:

```
<li class="hidden">
<li class="page-scroll">
<li class="page-scroll">
<li class="page-scroll">
<li class="page-scroll active">
```

Furthermore, when a `li` is clicked (or a certain part of a page is scrolled to) it doesn't update it's class to `:active`, the above list is static (for want of a better word) - it never changes!

Is anyone aware of a bug that causes this to happen? Or any possible solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: note that the `:active` selector and a class named `active` are different things, which do you mean? Also, have you closed your `li` with `</li>`?

Comment: `:active` is not a class...it's a pseudo-class that indicates that the element has a mousedown 'click' on it.

Comment: Yes, all `<li>` are closed and sorry yes I meant `.active` class, I am not sure why I put the pseudo-class representation. Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a JS/JQ error. not a CSS one.

Comment: I've figured out a solution, and I couldn't tell you if I would define it as a CSS or a JQ error. You tell me.

Comment: thanks for all your help :] appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other solution is:

Replace this line in the bootstrap.js

`scrollHeight = this.$scrollElement[0].scrollHeight || this.$body[0].scrollHeight`

with this line:

`scrollHeight = $(document).height()`

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery used for the page (and the scrolling feature) is the bootstrap scrollSpy.
My CSS has both `body` and `html` set as `height: 100%`. When using Opera the `scrollHeight` and `maxScroll` do not calculate correctly when ! This means that the navbar does not update correctly. I can't tell you why this bug occurs and why it only occurs in Opera.

The solution then is to remove `height: 100%` from `body` - it then works perfectly (except now there is presentation problems).

Anyone other solutions?